# How to compute the outputs at the transient ignoring subthreshold conduction and body effect

Tags: mosfet, dc

[image]

I tried solving the `Va` by computing the `Vs` of the second MOS as following:

> Vd1-Vs1 = Vdd - Vtn
> Vd2-Vs2 = Vs1-Vtn
> The value of `Vs2 = Va`.

Am I solving it correctly or am I completely off the track? If so, could you guide me on how to proceed for both nMOS and pMOS cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation

> Vd2-Vs2 = **Vs1-Vtn**

is not correct.

As this is a homework problem, I can give you some hints to help you solve the problem.

1. Current will flow through an NMOS until VG-VS > VTn because your question says that you can ignore sub-threshold conduction (i.e., when VG-VS =< VTn, you can assume current through the NMOS = 0).
2. Likewise, current will flow through a PMOS until VS-VG > |VTp|. When VS-VG =< |VTp|, current will stop flowing through the PMOS.
3. Start from the first transistor where VD and VG are defined. You then have to compute VS. VS will get set based on the above 2 conditions. Note VD-VS could also become zero as long as VG-VS > VTHn. This is what happens to the second NMOS which is connected to VA.
4. Lastly, when current flows into a high impedance node like a Gate or a capacitor, the voltage starts increasing linearly until the current stops.